# Local Jax variable not updating in `jit`ted function, but updating in standard?

Tags: python, jax

So, I've got some code and I could really use help deciphering the behavior and how to get it to do what I want.

See my code as follows:

```py
from typing import Callable, List

import chex
import jax.numpy as jnp
import jax

Weights = List[jnp.ndarray]


@chex.dataclass(frozen=True)
class Model:
    mult: Callable[
        [jnp.ndarray],
        jnp.ndarray
    ]

    jitted_mult: Callable[
        [jnp.ndarray],
        jnp.ndarray
    ]

    weight_updater: Callable[
        [jnp.ndarray], None
    ]


def create_weight():
    return jnp.ones((2, 5))


def wrapper():
    weights = create_weight()

    def mult(input_var):
        return weights.dot(input_var)

    @jax.jit
    def jitted_mult(input_var):
        return weights.dot(input_var)

    def update_locally_created(new_weights):
        nonlocal weights
        weights = new_weights
        return weights

    return Model(
        mult=mult,
        jitted_mult=jitted_mult,
        weight_updater=update_locally_created
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tester = wrapper()
    to_mult = jnp.ones((5, 2))
    for i in range(5):
        print(jnp.sum(tester.mult(to_mult)))
        print(jnp.sum(tester.jitted_mult(to_mult)))

        if i % 2 == 0:
            tester.weight_updater(jnp.zeros((2, 5)))
        else:
            tester.weight_updater(jnp.ones((2, 5)))

        print("*" * 10)
```

TL;DR I'm defining some "weights" within a function closure, and I'm trying to modify the weights via a `nonlocal`. The problem seems to be that the `jit`-ted version (`jitted_mult` of the function doesn't recognize the "updated" weights, whereas the non-jit function (`mult`) does.

What can I do to make it recognize the update? I **think** that I might be able to do what [Build your own Haiku](https://dm-haiku.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/build_your_own_haiku.html) does, but that seems like a lot of work for an experiment

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to match your code. `jitted_mult` just returns the inputs: did you meant for `jitted_mult` to return `weights.dot(input_var)`, just as the un-jitted `mult` does?

Comment: Yes! Sorry. I've updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working as expected: the reason it's not respecting the update is because your function is not pure (see [JAX Sharp Bits: Pure Functions](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Common_Gotchas_in_JAX.html#pure-functions)). In your case, the function is not pure because the output depends on an input that is not explicitly passed to the function. This violates the assumptions made by `jit` and other JAX transformations, which leads to unexpected behavior.

To fix it I would make this implicit input explicit, so that your function is pure. It might look something like this:

```py
def wrapper():
    def mult(input_var, weights):
        return weights.dot(input_var)

    @jax.jit
    def jitted_mult(input_var, weights):
        return weights.dot(input_var)

    return Model(
        mult=mult,
        jitted_mult=jitted_mult,
        weight_updater=None
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tester = wrapper()
    to_mult = jnp.ones((5, 2))
    weights = create_weight()
    for i in range(5):
        print(jnp.sum(tester.mult(to_mult, weights)))
        print(jnp.sum(tester.jitted_mult(to_mult, weights)))

        if i % 2 == 0:
            weights = jnp.zeros((2, 5))
        else:
            weights = jnp.ones((2, 5))

        print("*" * 10)
```

Comment: Hey again! Yeah, I wasn't sure if SO was the right place to post the original question since fewer people use this tag. I'm marking you correct; thank you!